# Lenovo W530 Nvidia Optimus - Second Screen not recognized

Tags: fedora, nvidia, optimus

I have a Lenovo W530 with Fedora 33 (KDE).
`5.11.13-200.fc33.x86_64`

The Notebook has to Graphic processors

```
lspci | grep -e "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] (rev a1)

lspci -k | grep -EA3 "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 21f5
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 21f5
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I do have the following Settings active in BIOS:

- UEFI Secure Boot: Off.
- Graphics Device: NVIDIA Optimus (andere optionen wären Integrated und Discrete)
- OS Detection for NVIDIA Optimus: Enabled

Two Problems:
First of all my a second screen is not detected. Neither via mini-display-port nor via vga.
While playing DOTA 2 as soon as I increase graphics quality higher then the absolut minimum the shadows start flipping on an off and framedrops occur. I believe this to be related to the currently active (low performance) Intel graphics chip. I wanted to test that with the NVIDIA chip but currently I'm blocked due to the not launchable `nvidia-settings`.

I know that the Intel chip is currently active due to the system information window in KDE which tells me  `Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4000` as Graphics Processor.

I have "activated" the rpm fusion repos and also installed the nvidia drivers.

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

Additionally:

```
lsmod | grep -e "nvidia"
nvidia_drm             69632  0
nvidia_modeset       1232896  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34177024  1 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        286720  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   622592  15 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

My questions:

- Is the second screen problem related to the nvidia driver?

  - If yes, what is still needed to make them work.
  - If no, what may the actual problem be
- Why is it not possible for `nvidia-settings` to load the info?
- Is there anything else I have to take care of? / Do I miss something important here?